# Creating a Global Object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object

I'm trying to achieve the following:

When a user has been successfully authenticated, I need to create a Global user object which I can access from different Forms (or classes).

I was looking through the Data Sources available in VS, and saw there's a "Object" option which may be suitable for what I'm trying to achieve. The trouble is, I have no idea how it works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what information do these various "forms or classes" require from this "user object"?

Comment: just the ability to read (and possibly modify) it's attributes. Via properties.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is a Windows Forms application, you can create a User class that is stored in a static ApplicationState class.

Steps:

1) Create your user class to hold information about the user:

```
public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    //.. other properties
}
```

2) Create your ApplicationState class:

```
public static class ApplicationState
{
    public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

3) In your login process, create a new version of the user class and assign it to the ApplicationState.CurrentUser property:

```
    public void CompleteLogin(string sLogin)
    {
        User user = new User();

        user.Login = sLogin;

        ApplicationState.CurrentUser = user;
    }
```

4) You can now use `ApplicationState.CurrentUser` just about anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and it's a Bad Thing (especially when its state can be mutated). Investigate [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) instead. There's even a [.NET-specific book](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) on it.

Per request, here's a simple (probably oversimplified) example of doing DI manually. A [DI Container library](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) (also known as an Inversion of Control or IoC Container library) can simplify the process of "wiring everything up" in the composition root, and usually also provides lifetime management and other features.

```
// Composition root of your application
void Main()
{
    // Only instance of user we will ever create
    var user = new User();

    var instance = new MyClass(user);
}

public interface IUser
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User: IUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IUser user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        _user = user;
    }

    private readonly IUser _user;
}
```

Comment: +1 for dependency injection. It may be worth adding a brief example of how to do this manually as a basic step, with a reference to automatic DI via an IoC container as an advanced alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use or create a public List making sure that you only add the authenticated users to the List once they have been validated you could even do this via encapsulating field access, create a List or string[] property what you are asking you probably would want to create a class level Property.