# creating a global object in nodejs accessible by .js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

My nodejs project requires memory tables accessible by different .js module. Some modules will update the tables but the data must be the same across all modules(sort of a in memory db). As such, I need a truly global object....not a global per module object. Creating a **common.js** file with all the objects then **require** it in all the modules will not do since the data will be global/local to the respective modules. I have seen reference to **nodejs globals** where **global.myobject** would be global to all modules but the documentation is not clear as to whether this is so or not. The last discussion I saw was from 2014. Can anyone update me on what is the current situation? How is this problem solved?

Comment: Having a common.js and exporting an object literal, would be global to all modules that required it..

Comment: Actually, requiring the same `common.js` from the other modules *will* do. Every module is instantiated only once, regardless how often it is required. It's exactly what you need - a singleton.

Comment: @Bergi a somewhat similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555792/creating-a-global-object  from 2011 suggested a singleton but also advised against it. Can you demonstrate how this would work and the pros and cons?

Comment: @Keith are you saying that by requiring the common.js the changes made to its objects would be reflected in the next module that required it? I am not sure of that. Can you point to some docs that support this?

Comment: @MichaelE That's a C# question which doesn't really apply here. Yes, a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is usually a bad idea exactly because it's global state, but that's what you asked for. Make a module and export an object, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

In node.js..

if you had a module called common.js, that looked like this..

```
'use strict';

var obj = {};
module.exports = obj;
```

And then inside another module you did this

```
'use strict';
var c = require('./common');
c.test = 1234;
```

Then later another module did this..

```
'use strict';
var c = require('./common');
console.log(c);
//output = { test: 1234 }
```

A module in modejs, is just another object.  nodejs, caches any requires, and so will always return the same object.

One gotcha for windows users, windows filenames are not case-sensitive,  so if you did require('Common'), and then did require('common'); you would have 2 version of the same module.  And this is a good reason to keep all modules names in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the examples...the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140661/global-variables-for-node-js-standard-modules/4141647#4141647  speaks to **global.myobject** do you have any comments on this alternative

Comment: The problem with global.myobject, is that of scope.  The advantage of using a common.js file would be it's a global that's scoped to your modules's.. If for some reason there were other third party library's that wanted to share info, then the global.myobject could maybe be used.  IOW: The global is a bit like browsers window object.